# Missing input files for rule all, but should be present

Tags: snakemake

When running my Snakemake pipeline, I am getting the following error:

```
MissingInputException in line 19 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
results/hisat2/featureCounts/all.fixed.featureCounts
results/star/featureCounts/all.fixed.featureCounts
```

Below is my main Snakefile. Afterwards, I have the `rules/featurecounts.smk` which is related to this error.

It seems like I have a rule definition that should prevent this error.

Snakefile:

```yaml
configfile: "config.yaml"

units = pd.read_table(config["units"], dtype=str).set_index(["sample", "unit"], drop=False)
units.index = units.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in units.index.levels])  # enforce str in index
aligners=config["params"]["aligners"].split(",")
print("Aligners:", aligners)


##### target rules #####

rule all:
    input:
        "qc/multiqc_report_pretrim.html",
        "qc/multiqc_report_posttrim.html",
        expand("qc/multiqc_report_{aligner}.html", aligner=aligners),
        expand("results/{aligner}/featureCounts/all.fixed.featureCounts", aligner=aligners)

##### setup report #####

report: "report/workflow.rst"


##### load rules #####

#include: "rules/common.smk"
include: "rules/qc.smk"
include: "rules/trim.smk"
include: "rules/align.smk"
include: "rules/featurecounts.smk"
```

featurecounts.smk file

```yaml
rule featurecounts_onefile_star:
    input:
        sam=expand("star/{unit.sample}.{unit.unit}/{unit.sample}.{unit.unit}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", unit=units.itertuples()),
        annotation=config["ref"]["annotation"],
        fasta=config["ref"]["genomefa"]     # implicitly sets the -G flag
    output:
        multiext("results/star/featureCounts/all",
                 ".featureCounts",
                 ".featureCounts.summary",
                 ".featureCounts.jcounts")
    log:
        "logs/star/featurecount/all.log"
    params:
        tmp_dir="",   # implicitly sets the --tmpDir flag
        r_path="",    # implicitly sets the --Rpath flag
        #extra="-p -C -t exon -g gene_id --extraAttributes gene_name,transcript_id,transcript_name"   #-p to count fragments instead of reads, -C to not count fragments if mapped to different chrs, -t exon (only consider exons, -g look at the gene_id field to get the feature name
        extra="{}".format(config["params"]["featurecounts"])
    threads: 8
    resources: time_min=220, mem_mb=20000, cpus=8
    wrapper:
        "0.69.0/bio/subread/featurecounts"

rule featurecounts_onefile_hisat2:
    input:
        sam=expand("hisat2/{unit.sample}.{unit.unit}.sorted.bam", unit=units.itertuples()),
        annotation=config["ref"]["annotation"],
        fasta=config["ref"]["genomefa"]     # implicitly sets the -G flag
    output:
        multiext("results/hisat2/featureCounts/all",
                 ".featureCounts",
                 ".featureCounts.summary",
                 ".featureCounts.jcounts")
    log:
        "logs/hisat2/featurecount/all.log"
    params:
        tmp_dir="",   # implicitly sets the --tmpDir flag
        r_path="",    # implicitly sets the --Rpath flag
        #extra="-p -C -t exon -g gene_id --extraAttributes gene_name,transcript_id,transcript_name"   #-p to count fragments instead of reads, -C to not count fragments if mapped to different chrs, -t exon (only consider exons, -g look at the gene_id field to get the feature name
        extra="{}".format(config["params"]["featurecounts"])
    threads: 8
    resources: time_min=220, mem_mb=20000, cpus=8
    wrapper:
        "0.69.0/bio/subread/featurecounts"

rule fix_featurecounts:
    input:
        "results/{aligner}/featureCounts/all.featureCounts"
    output:
        "results/{aligner}/featureCounts/all.fixed.featureCounts"
    log:
        "logs/{aligner}/featurecount/fix.log"
    threads: 1
    resources: time_min=220, mem_mb=2000, cpus=1
    shell:
        "python3 ../scripts/fix_featurecounts_output.py -f {input} -c 2 > {output} 2> {log}"
```

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like this should work. One idea: go back in what you request as output step by step, to further pin down what causes the error. So try to remove the `.fixed` infix in `rule all` first and then go further back, rule by rule. But it does look like the problem should be `rule fix_featurecounts` not being seen for some reason. Maybe some `include: ` commented out by accident or something?

Comment: If i comment out the .fixed line in `rule all`, it says there is nothing to be done. I am sure I have the necessary files included. I could commit this to a github project to let you read the full source code.

Comment: I meant simply removing the `.fixed` part from the requested file name in `rule all`. This would instead request the input of the rule that produces the `.fixed` file and not request nothing to be done. That way you can work back to a point where the pipeline works, and then at least know where your problem originates.

Comment: This question is really too specific for Stackoverflow. You need to boil it down to a minimal reproducible example, that people can run. On the way there, you will probably find the bug yourself. There is too much code you didn't provide, and cannot provide on SO, that's not what it's for. When I got rid of all seemingly superfluous stuff like references to other files, it ran. So the problem is somewhere in the code you didn't provide. Like an include not working etc.
Try to copy the `fix_featurecounts` rule over into your Snakefile as a start. That should change the error etc.